# Compile C program to run everywhere?

Tags: c, assembly, process, intel, amd-processor

I understand that when the C compiler compiles code, it compiles it into machine code that is specific to the processor that it was compiled on. Is it possible to compile my C program on an Intel machine for example, and have it run on an AMD one without needing to recompile it on a machine with an AMD processor?

Comment: What development stack are you talking about?

Comment: x86 intel and x86 amd are, for the most part, compatible. There are however differences between supported instruction subsets (such as SSE or AVX), cpu features or optimization guidelines even between models of the same manufacturer. You should compile for the common subset supported by all the processors you are targeting.

Comment: @ChrisBallard By development stack do you just mean what am I using? I'm using an Intel based Mac but I'd like to compile for machine with different processors.

Comment: @Jester Are there any good cross compilers?

Comment: @user3318845 GCC Cross Compilers - http://cowlark.com/2009-07-04-building-gcc/  Just change target to what you want... (this one has ARM)

Comment: FYI, x64 was developed by AMD as an extension to 32-bit instruction set and later supported by Intel. So the question could have been asked the other way round too...

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen I just like Intel more, there's no particular reason. It's probably just better marketing. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact both common Intel and AMD processors are based on X86 architecture. Although C program cannot be compiled once and run "everywhere", but Intel and AMD processors are really the same place in this sense.

For example you don't really worry about a single executable (say a game installer) wont be able to run on your windows machine regardless of it's Intel or AMD inside.

It's other architectures (different instruction set) such as Mac/ARM/68k etc you need to worry about recompiling

Comment: However, if the OP compiles for MacOS X/Intel, this executable won't run under Windows on Intel (or AMD). CPU is not the only variable.